# How to get values separated by commas while ignoring comma in square brackets?

Tags: java, opencsv

CSV Values are separated like below:

sample.csv

```
1,2,[3,4],5
```

CSV Reader:

```java
final CsvToBean<Numbers> csvReader = new CsvToBeanBuilder(fileReader)
                 .withType(SurveyInputCSVDataBean.class)
                 .withSeparator(',')
                 .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                 .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
                 .withThrowExceptions(false)
                 .withIgnoreQuotations(false)
                 .build();
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Required Result:

```
1
2
3,4
5
```

Comment: FYI, section 2.6 of the [CSV specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) requires fields that contain a comma to be delimited by straight double-quote characters. Square brackets should not be used for that purpose.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, OpenCSV has no configuration to use separate start and end quote characters, though you can probably subclass the CSVParser and overrides its `parseLine` or `parseLineMulti` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your own separator to split the input string after reading from CSV file. Here is an example that solves your problem and produces the desired output.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "1,2,[3,4],5";
        String[] tokens = line.split(",(?![^\\[]*\\])");
        for (String t : tokens) {
            System.out.println(t.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
        }
    }
```